# Unfortunately app has stopped when I use onClickListener for a button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I have no idea why my code isn't working. I am following a tutorial on how to add a listener to buttons but my app doesn't even run anymore. I'm sure it's a silly mistake but I've been stuck for over 5 hours!. Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.simplebuttons;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //System.out.print("HELLO");
        addListenerOnButton();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGoStraight);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a simple button app. \r\n \r\nCode Here \r\n"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGoStraight"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/go_straight"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTurnLeft"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/turn_left"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTurnRight"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/turn_right" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGoBack"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/go_back" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="\n"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGoBack"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/destination" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.simplebuttons.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

This is the logcat:
[image]

Do anyone have any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: what does you main_activity.xml look like? you buttons are in the fragment but you are trying to find them in the activity_main.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Button with `buttonGoStraight` id is inside `fragment_main` layout which is `PlaceholderFragment` Fragment layout so call `addListenerOnButton` in `onCreateView` and use `rootView` for accessing  views:

```
    Button b1 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonGoStraight);
```

Comment: Now I am getting an error with the `Toast` in MainActivity.java

Comment: @Alias : use `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext()` as first parameter in `makeText`

Comment: @Alias: also move `addListenerOnButton` method inside `PlaceholderFragment` class

Comment: Toast should cope with application context as well, that part seems irrelevant. Also note that *if* you want to keep the listener logic in your activity you can use getFragmentManager to get your fragment by id or tag, then call getView and findViewById on the returned root view.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to findViewById on R.layout.activity_main, but your button is located on the fragment's layout... You should set the button's listener in the onCreateView in the PlaceholderFragment

Comment: Now I am getting an error with the `Toast` in MainActivity.java

Comment: It says `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApplicationContext() from the type ContextWrapper`

Comment: From where is that call?

Comment: instead of getApplicationContext() write getActivity()

Answer (score 0):

You're calling findViewById *before* adding the fragment that contains this element. Move the listener setup code after the fragment initialization.

Comment: Now I am getting an error with the `Toast` in MainActivity.java